# Missing dependencie for realvnc-vnc-viewer in arch Linux (libcrypt.so.1)

Tags: archlinux, vnc-viewer

A dependency (libcrypt.so.1) is missing when I try to launch realvnc-vnc-viewer on arch Linux. It prompted these error each time I try to launch vnc-viewer with command line : `vncviewer: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypt.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`
I have libcrypt.so at version 2.0, but it seems that vnc-viewer only work with version one.I have downloaded realvnc-vnc-viewer with pacman and I can't launch the app anymore.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please refer to the latest comments in [realvnc-vnc-viewer AUR page](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/realvnc-vnc-viewer).

For now, there are 2 solutions. I am using solution 2 and can confirm it is working.

### Solution 1

Symlink `libcrypt.so.2.0.0` to `libcrypt.so.1`

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libcrypt.so.2.0.0 /usr/lib/libcrypt.so.1
```

### Solution 2

Install [libxcrypt-compat](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/realvnc-vnc-viewer)

Comment: thanks - vnc broke on my arch linux box after running a pacman -Su and this fixed it

Comment: You are amazing ! Thank you SO much